# Stokes' vectors and quaternions

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, polarization, complex-numbers

About a month ago, I was presented in my Optics class (classical and electromagnetic optics, to be more precise) the representation of partially polarised light through Stokes' vectors. Now, it occurred to me that instead of representing them with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, perhaps it could be more benefitial to represent them using quaternions. I feel like this would simplify calculations a great deal, since Mueller matrices could now be 2-dimensional instead of 4-dimensional (I deduce this from the fact that quaternions can be written as 2x2 matrices, and since a Mueller matrix transforms a Stokes' vector into another Stokes' vector, then the only dimension a matrix could have to transform a 2x2 matrix representing a quaternion into another quaternion is, precisely, 2x2). Computationally, this would require much less effort, I reckon, since a machine would only have to work with lower dimension matrices. Would it be of any interest to implement this? If so, I assume it's already being implemented. Where, exactly, can we see this use of quaternions in Optics? If my proposed representation is not of any interest or does not hold, where exactly did I go wrong?

As usual, thanks for your kind responses!

Comment: Are not stokes parameters exactly quaternions: https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.36.000492

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link, that's exactly what I was looking for!